# Images are not show in the debug apk - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, adb

Hi I'm new to react native. I have created react native application and for testing I have get the debug apk as output. But once I installed on debug APK on real device some Images are not showing.. Anything wrong I have done ?

Comment: DId you bundle all the assets before generating debig apk ? And which OS are you in ? Mac or Windows ?

Comment: @AkilaDevinda I'm on Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't bundle your assets before generating **debug apk**

Try this code in your terminal for bundle all the assets and get **debug apk** as output

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: Yes I think this will help me.. Thanks